# Is there a way such as with @JsonFilter to print only values of a HashMap?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want my maps to only print the values when serialized to JSON. Something along the lines of this filter which is used to format Dates

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
LocalDate startDate;
```

Comment: sorry where is the Map here ? what is your question?

Comment: Please provide an expected input and output.

Comment: `@JsonIgnore` the map and create a custom getter for your list-of-values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have an object with a Map as a field and you want to serialize this object, but instead of key-value-pairs for the map-property, you want to instead only print the values in a list, you could have a custom getter for this transformation:

```
public class MyTest {

    private Map<String, Object> myMapProperty = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    public Map<String, Object> getMyMapProperty() {
        return myMapProperty;
    }

    public void setMyMapProperty(final Map<String, Object> myMapProperty) {
        this.myMapProperty = myMapProperty;
    }

    @JsonProperty("myMapProperty")
    public List<Object> getMyMapPropertyValues() {
        return myMapProperty.values()
                .stream() // use .map to transform values, e.g. flatten if values are Lists themselves
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        final MyTest myObject = new MyTest();
        myObject.getMyMapProperty().put("k1", "value1");
        myObject.getMyMapProperty().put("k2", "value2");

        final String value = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myObject);
        System.out.println(value);
    }

}
```